# make notification circle in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I want a show notification. I write custom code to count row and show notification circle with count but some problem occur it's not display all globally.

```
global $wpdb;
        $id=get_current_user_ID();
        $order_table=$wpdb->prefix.'buyer_order_request';
        $matched_table=$wpdb->prefix.'matched_order_details';
        $table2=$wpdb->prefix.'my_new_productsdetail';
        $query="SELECT * FROM $matched_table INNER JOIN $order_table ON $matched_table.order_req_id =$order_table.order_request_id WHERE $matched_table.order_supplier_id = $id AND $matched_table.matched_acpt='0' AND $matched_table.decline_reason=''";
        $results=$wpdb->get_results($query);
        $rowCount = $wpdb->num_rows;
        $user = new WP_User( $id );
            $curren_user_role=$user->roles[0];
            if($curren_user_role=='supplier')
            {
                ?>
                <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    var noti_count=jQuery('#row-counts').val();
                    if(noti_count>0)
                    { 
                      jQuery('.button__badge').css({"backgroundColor": "red", "color": "white"});
                      jQuery('.button__badge').text(noti_count);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                         jQuery('.button__badge').hide();
                    }
                });
                </script>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rowCount; ?>" id="row-counts">
                <?
           }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: is user logged in? because you pick current user, so you have to logged in when you need result.

Comment: @OmarFaruque i put code according to my need. i want to show notification only "supplier" user not another

Comment: @FrankerZ it's working fine but it's show notification when i reached on "order page menu" not all page when i click on another menu than it's not display notification